# Show Record if An Entry Does Not Exist For it

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

In my Sql table, when a value is entered in, the date is recorded with it. The problem is, I want to show all the values(dynamically created buttons in my case) that do not have a date entered for today's date (DateTime.Today).
How would I do this if that entry has not even been added in for the day?

EDIT: The date is within the SQL table, but also in a listview filled with data from the sql table for easy access. The buttons should only be shown for those that do not have a date entered for today.

```
public void load()
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView.Items)
            {
               //item.SubItems[5].Text is row's ID
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                string strsql = "SELECT ID from Table1 WHERE ID = '" + item.SubItems[5].Text + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Button test1Button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                    test1Button.Click+= new EventHandler(button1ButtonClick);
                    test1Button .Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                    test1Button .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 38);
                    this.Controls.Add(test1Button );
                    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(test1Button );

                    System.Windows.Forms.Button test2Button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                   test2Button Button.Click += new EventHandler(LabelBtn_Click);
                     test2Button Button.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                     test2Button Button.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                     test2Button Button.ForeColor = Color.White;
                     test2Button Button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 38);
                    this.Controls.Add( test2Button );
                   flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add( test2Button );

                }

            }
        }
```

***UPDATE:***
I have updated the code, I realized I needed to join tables, and with the joining of these tables I have better access to the dates. The dates are not null, they simply are not entered at all yet for the day. The date does not exist in the database at all until the user enters in a result.

```
public void load()
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView.Items)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                string strsql = "SELECT * from Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN  Table2 AS t2 ON t1.[Table1 _ID] = t2.[Table2 _ID] WHERE Convert(Date, yourDateColumn) > Convert(Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
             
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Button test1Button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                    test1Button .Click += new EventHandler(button1ButtonClick);
                    test1Button .Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                    test1Button .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 38);
                    this.Controls.Add(test1Button );
                    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(test1Button );

                    System.Windows.Forms.Button test2Button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                    test2Button .Click += new EventHandler(LabelBtn_Click);
                    test2Button .Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                   test2Button .BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    test2Button .ForeColor = Color.White;
                    test2Button .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 38);
                    this.Controls.Add(test2Button );
                    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(test2Button );

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code creates a new button for every record from the query result. Where is a date here?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Edited my question for a better understanding.

Comment: "that do not have a date entered for today's date (DateTime.Now)" you mean `DateTime.Today` not `DateTime.Now`?!

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is correct, still fairly new to coding.

Comment: The ID gets the entire row of values, values that include a date. ```item.SubItems[5].Text``` is the ID for the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should really avoid constructing your queries like that, you're opening your application to security risks. Look into using the AddWithValue method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Also, if you say the date is in the database just extract it in your query, which I can't seem to understand because it seems to me you are currently extracting only the ID, but based on the ID... Better do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Convert(Date,yourDateColumn) != Convert(Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This way you only select the rows from your table where the date IS NOT today's date.

Also, you seem to be adding the buttons twice, once to the form and once to a flowLayoutPanel, which I think is unnecessary, just add it to the panel.

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, but the issue is that it would give me all the values before today, and I do not want those.

Comment: Ok then, are there rows where the date is null or empty? If that's the case then you could just change the query to :... WHERE date = null.  That would give you only the rows that have not yet been given a date value. 

Otherwise, we would need more information on the structure of your table or your actual requirements in order to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, now you have me guessing that the table that you are joining is the one that holds the dates. If that is the case do the following query:

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)

Either way, you really need to provide better information in your questions, like the schema of your tables, because otherwise no one will know what you're talking about or how to help you.